# Softlayer http API for sending file to object storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am not so good in API so you may find my question to simple, but I have spent days looking around and found nothing.

I want to be able to copy a file from my server to my Object Storage in Softlayer using a simple http url where I will put inside all necessary info, like, username, key, path of local file to copy, destination object storage and directory, ....

I am looking for something like this:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/xcopy?file="file.jpg&user=joejoe&key=1234567YUIO ....
```

I have only found curl but I do not know how it works and this is not what I need.

```
$ curl -i -XPUT -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkb26239d441d6401d9482b004d45f7259" --data-binary "Created for testing REST client" 
https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_df0de35c-d00a-40aa-b697-2b7f1b9331a6/container2/file10.txt
    HTTP/1.1 201 Created
    Content-Length: 118
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Etag: 8ba9b504dc5961b4e328f9446f0a4f15
    Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Apr 2014 20:21:23 GMT
    X-Trans-Id: tx0263bbf654474189b73453dfcd8c59df
    Date: Thu, 17 Apr 2014 20:21:23 GMT
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I do not think such thing is possible, the softlayer object storage is based on open stack, so maybe you can find what you are looking for in the open stack documentation.

What I know you need to use curl. curl is a command line tool for getting or sending files using URL syntax.

you need to install curl or the swift client see more information here http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis

then you can upload files like this:

```
curl -X PUT -T myFile.jpg  -H "X-Auth-Token: 3c5c8187-2569-47e0-8a11-edadd384e12b" https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_df0de35c-d00a-40aa-b697-2b7f1b9331a6/container2/myFile.jpg
```

see here more information about curl

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/cloud-files-curl-cookbook/

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install python-swiftclient
```

Export the authentication credentials to simplify later steps:

```
export ST_AUTH=

export ST_USER=

export ST_KEY=

swift upload container_name file_name
```

or

```
swift upload container_name file_name -A {authentication_endpoint} -K {api_key} -U {swift_username}
```

for more help run this command on command line:

```
swift upload --help
```